# What do robot parts do?

Tags: starbound

After creating the metalwork station, I am able to construct various robot parts, such as legs, arms, and chest parts.  I cannot yet make a head (no artificial brain), and I cannot make the robot crafting station, but I am quite curious what will happen if I try to construct this robot.

What do these robot parts do, and is it a good idea to use my resources to build a robot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have built the full [Inactive Robot](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Inactive_Robot), you can place it on the surface of a planet and activate it to fight a boss enemy. On being defeated, that boss will drop a [Processor](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Processor) item, needed to make a [more advanced crafting table](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Robotic_Crafting_Table), which itself is then used to create a better star map, and proceed to the next sector.

In short, yes, you will eventually need to make the robot to keep advancing. But, you may not want to make it too immediate a priority, as the boss may be difficult to defeat if you've only just unlocked the Metalwork Station.